# Do we have disadvantage of using $scope.$watch and $scope.$watchCollection?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

My colleague keeps telling we should not use `$scope.$watch` and  `$scope.$watchCollection`.

Do we have disadvantage of using  `$scope.$watch` and `$scope.$watchCollection` ?

Comment: Did you ask this question to your colleague ? If you add reason also with this question why your colleague is telling to not use, then your question will be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you use too many of them, then you might see some performance impact because watch expressions will be executed as part of $digest loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of watches:

1.Reference watch   -- `$watch`

2.collection watch   -- `$watchCollection`

Usually `$watch` is applicable for keeping track of scope variables and the changes of their values.

Ex: if you want to keep track of a scope variable you should use `$watch`

```
$scope.$watch("variableName", function(newValue, oldValue){
});
```

if you want to keep track of an array you should use `$watchCollection`

```
$scope.$watchCollection("arrayName", function(newValue, oldValue){
});
```